# readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle DIR

Tags: perl, regex-negation

I want to open directory and get all file names in that directory and not the sub directories. Please help me to correct in this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
my $opt_section;
my $opt_content;
my $opt_help = 0;

 &GetOptions (
"help"          => \$opt_help,
"section:s"        => \$opt_section,
"content:s"        => \$opt_content,
);

if ($opt_help) {
print "USAGE: file.pl -section <section> -content <content> \n ";

    exit;}

my $dir ="/home/priya/scripts/test/${opt_section}/${opt_content}/latest";                             #base directory to look up for the files

print"$dir \n";

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Unable to read Directory : $!";
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        #Only files not subdirectories
        next unless (-f "$dir/$file");
        #Use a regular expression to find files ending in .txt
        $file =~ m/^${opt_section}.+txt$/i;
print "$file \n";

closedir(DIR);
}
exit 0;
```

I am getting this error while executing

it is reading first file and giving it name as output and then given this error

readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle DIR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error would have been obvious if you had properly indented your code. The `closedir` is inside your loop!